What does "lockup" mean in this context?
This context comes from the movie "Sling Blade" (1996).
(Karl is a person who was committed to a mental institution when he was a kid and who recently got out. The person speaking is his boss who was asked to hire Karl by the warden of the mental hospital that Karl was in)
You know, Karl,
I got to thinking about it last night, and it's just not Christian of me not to let you have a key. I mean, you've been in lockup so long, you don't need me keeping you locked up.

Does "lockup" in this context mean:

A being locked up, as in jail.?(Collins Dictionary)
In other words. Does it mean "a state of being locked and not being able to leave"?

Why do Collins and other dictionaries have this definition as "a being locked up" and not "being locked up"? The noun "being" doesn't carry the same meaning as far as I can tell.

being(noun):
a person or thing that exists, or the state of existing:
[ C ] human/living beings
[ U ] The group came into being (= began to exist) to help relatives of the terminally
This noun is also in its uncounted form when it's used in this way, as you can see in this Cambridge dictionary's definition.

I've never heard "lockup" being used that way, but it is completely obvious to me that "lockup" means "secure mental institution, given the context. It's being used in the same way as you would say "being in hospital", "in prison" or "in jail".

"lockup" in the US is a slang term for jail or prison. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ud3RIT3TxDQ      I don't know the movie. Maybe it's a hospital for the criminally insane, which have much tighter security measures. Patients are not free to leave.

It means the looney bin. Frankly, with that dictionary definition, I don't understand how this isn't abundantly clear.

Sometimes it pays to check multiple dictionaries and weigh them against each other to find consensus. Collins collates entries from other dictionaries. The one you're referencing is credited as "Webster’s New World College Dictionary, 4th Edition." For me, right below it, is another entry labeled "Most material © 2005, 1997, 1991 by Penguin Random House LLC." This one puts "a jail" as definition #1, the act of locking up as #2, the state of being imprisoned as #3, and etc., moving on to specialized uses like in printing. It doesn't have anything resembling this mysterious "a being" entry. Neither does online Merriam-Webster or even Wiktionary.
So the first thing I would do with a puzzling and rare entry that doesn't seem immediately useful to me is ignore it and focus on all the other available dictionaries. If we must make sense of it, I thing the best reading is to insert "state of":

A state of being locked up, as in jail

I can't really explain why it worded it as it did. I doubt that it actually meant "a being [a living thing] that is locked up," since no other dictionary (or usage that I've heard of) supports that definition.

'Lockup' most often refers to jail/prison, but can also extend to persons detained in other kinda of institution such as mental hospitals. If you're institutionalised and not free to leave then you're in lockup.
